# Single user license - Minitab

Tags: single-user

We are using Minitab for statictical analysis and we have a single user license, for this year we don't have budget and we can't upgrade our license type to multi user.

We have installed Minitab in a single computer and asking different users to log in to the computer and analyze the data they have, this used to be the case from past one year. However the software (Minitab) has stopped functioning. We contacted Oracle and they had mentioned that we have to upgrade to multi user or should stop remote log ins.

The problem now is we don' t have budget and we need Minitab and we have to continue with the single user. Now I need your help in determining how do I continue with Single user and still ensure more than one user can log in to it remotely and do the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Do to the protections built into Minitab, you will have to talk to them about how upgrade to a "shared" license.

We find that many companies try to make do with a few copies of Minitab. For the same investment, you could get 10 copies of the QI Macros for Excel which does most of what Minitab does for a fraction of the price.